# iterate over JSON object response in angular 5

Tags: json, angular5

I'm having a JSON object from REST response which would like to loop over its items and display in the UI, this is the structure of the response:

```
 {"Items":
    {"releases":
    [{"last":"365147","first":"365987","relNo":"1","files":[{"fileId":"1","url":"http://....."},{"fileId":"2","url":"http://....."}}],"publish":"Yes"},{"last":"365147","first":"365987","relNo":"2","files":[{"fileId":"1","url":"https://...."},{"fileId":"2","url":"http://....."},{"fileId":"3","url":"...."},{"documentId":"4","url":"http://....."}],"publish":"No"}]}
```

on the service i'm doing this:

```
this.myService.getDetails(id).subscribe (data => {  
      this.items = data;
      console.log (JSON.stringify(this.items));
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your template you want an ngFor. Seems like you have a variable in your component named `items` so you would want something like:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
    {{item.releases}} // or item.whatever field you would like to access
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you :) yes I declared like items  = JSON [ ] ;
How can I access properties of releases...for example if would like to select from a drop-down list details of relNo.1 or relNo2,....etc.

Comment: In your component you should extract the releases and assign it to `items` so instead of having it be the entire JSON just get the `Items.releases`. This will give you an array. Then in your template you loop as in my answer and get the relNo by `{{ item.relNo }}`

Comment: Thanks for reply,You mean to declare items like items = JSON [items.relseases] , How to to extract the releases precisely?

Comment: In your api call: `this.items = data.Items.releases`

Comment: Should I use *ngFor to display the complete object result? For example relNo1 will be fetched form option 1 selected from the selection list...and so on

Comment: Yes you use ngFor to loop through `items` which will now contain the array of releases. Your ngFor will return `last`, `first`, `relNo`, `files`...etc. To access one of these fields you do `{{ item.fieldName }}` in your case you want the relNo you do `{{ item.relNo }}`

Comment: Great explanation, my aim was to fetch the details based on relNo. , So each time I change the selection from drop down selection the details (a complete release array) will be fetched